# Performance Testing - Need cloud machines in different regions ( India , Japan ,Europe)

Tags: cloud, performance-testing

I need some cloud linux machines in different regions for performance testing.
I want to simulate customer experience and I guess machines on AWS , google compute and Azure may not give use correct data as they might be using there own tunnel to give better performance

What is the best service that provides this other than AWS , google compute and MS Azure which I can use to do proper performance testing which matches with actual customer experience

Answer (score 1):

If you mean you want to simulate users accessing your website/webservice from different regions and locations then there are several hosted services which will do this:

- https://www.dotcom-tools.com/website-speed-test.aspx
- http://www.websitetest.com

or for mobile devices:

- http://www.keynote.com/solutions/testing/mobile-testing

Your concern about the test machines being from the same cloud provider and hence same network as the user is fair so you might want to check which ones use a different host.

Having said that, even within a region you will have different speeds from different access networks, different access price plans etc so you need to be careful not to take the results as absolute.

You also probably want to think about some sort of CDN technology if it is important for your site/service to have good responsiveness in different areas - essentially the CDN provider should take care of all those headaches for you.